# Partial sum of exponential series strictly increases after certain step

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, power-series, exponential-function

While trying to show that partial exponential series evaluated at two different values are strictly increasing provided that sufficient number of terms are applied I stuck at a problem. Given two rational numbers $p,q \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $p<q$, find  $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$ s. t. the following holds:

$$ \sum_{l=1}^{n} \frac{q^l - p^l}{l!} - \frac{|q|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} - \frac{|p|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} > \frac{1}{k}$$

The first term is the difference between two partial sums and the last two terms indicate the half-bounds in which the partial sums are located after $n$-th step. **I would like to obtain a solution of that inequality**, not a proof of existence of such $n$ and $k$.

---

It is possible to show that the inequality in the first place may be turned into this simplified one (for even $n$):

$$ \sum_{l=1}^{n} \frac{q^l - p^l}{l!} > \frac{1}{k} $$

It follows from the fact  that for even $n$:

$$ \sum_{l=0}^{n-g-1} \frac{p^l}{l!} > \sum_{l=0}^{n-g-3} \frac{p^l}{l!} $$

with $n \geq |p| + g + 1$. It is done by subtracting maximal values of bottom margins in consecutive terms.

Comment: Are you sure that you have two $-$ signs or missing parentheses ?

Comment: Thanks for precising ! I was just wondering because of symmetry.

Comment: Such $n,k$ can be found if and only if the left-hand side is positive for some $n$. Is that what you want to know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m=\lceil -\mathrm ep\rceil$. Then the ratio of magnitudes of successive terms beyond $m$ is less than $1/\mathrm e$. Now choose $n$ such that

$$
\frac{|p|^m}{m!}\frac1{1-1/\mathrm e}\mathrm e^{-(n-m)}\le\frac12\mathrm e^p\;.
$$

Since the $m$-th term has magnitude $|p|^m/m!$ and the magnitudes of the remaining terms are bounded by a geometric sequence with ratio $\mathrm e$, the terms beyond $n$ can add up to at most the left-hand side, and if this is bounded by the right-hand side, the sum up to $n$ must be positive, since the series converges to $\mathrm e^p$. Thus,

$$
n=\left\lceil m-p+\log\left(\frac2{1-1/\mathrm e}\frac{|p|^m}{m!}\right)\right\rceil
$$

ensures that

$$
\sum_{l=0}^{n} \frac{p^l}{l!}
$$

is positive.

Comment: @ValerySaharov: Certainly; if all you want is a bound, you can approximate to your heart's content. You can write $\log\left(\frac2{1-1/\mathrm e}\frac{|p|^m}{m!}\right)=\log\frac2{1-1/\mathrm e}+\log\frac{|p|^m}{m!}$ and bound the constant first term by some rational (e.g. $1.2$). For the second term you may have to be a bit more creative. For the logarithm of the factorial you could use the lower bounds on the factorial given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Rate_of_growth_and_approximations_for_large_n).

Comment: @ValerySaharov: Sure. I showed how to ensure that the partial sum $\sum_{l=0}^{n} \frac{p^l}{l!}$ is sufficiently close to its limit. You can use that to ensure that the two partial sums that you're subtracting are sufficiently close to their limits that their difference has to be positive (e.g. by ensuring that they're both within one third of the difference of the limits from their respective limits). Then you just have to choose $n$ large enough that the other two terms you're subtracting can't make the result negative.

Comment: @ValerySaharov: I think you should explain your setup in more detail. As far as I can tell, it seems to be somehow halfway between a proof and a concrete calculation on a machine. I've been thinking mostly in terms of a proof. If you want to do a calculation, you should explicate what it is you can use and what it is you want to compute.

Comment: @ValerySaharov: Your update doesn't help at all. It's not a matter of your "opinion", it's a matter of what you're trying to do, with what input, with what operations, with what intended results. I won't be investing any more time into this question until that's clearly spelled out.

Comment: @ValerySaharov: Sorry, I guess this must be as frustrating for you as it is for me. We seem to be talking past each other. I originally thought that you just wanted to solve the inequality in natural numbers $n$ and $k$. But the way I understand that phrase, I solved that problem. You then said (or at least that's what I understood) that you didn't want to use certain operations or certain numbers. You seemed to have in mind a certain limited set of available means that you were willing to employ. But when I inquire about them, you just repeat that you want to find $n$ and $k$.

Comment: @ValerySaharov: I just read your last update to the question. I still don't see in what sense my solution fails to fulfil those criteria. In particular, it requires a finite number of steps and contains no loops. I'm beginning to suspect that you have a particular model of computation in mind. If so, you'd need to explicate it. Alternatively, perhaps you could point out exactly where in my solution attempt I'm violating your computational constraints.

Comment: @ValerySaharov: I'm still wary of spending more time on this, since it seems the goal posts are constantly moving. Could you please explain this comment? "But I think I may not use their limits directly since I essentially approximate them" -- I still don't understand what you mean by this -- if you're looking for a proof, I don't see why you shouldn't be allowed to use the limits; if you're looking for some form of computation, you need to specify which computations are allowed and which aren't.

Comment: @ValerySaharov: Sorry, I'm really not going to be spending time on this unless you specify what operations are admissible (or explain what you meant by the above sentence, if not to constrain the admissible operations).

Comment: @ValerySaharov: This is really frustrating. I just quoted the sentence back to you. If you don't remember having written it, it's a simple search on the page text to find it again. I don't see how the sentence "But I think I may not use their limits directly since I essentially approximate them" can express doubts about finding an expression. We don't need to find an expression for the limits; we know them; they're $\mathrm e^p$ and $\mathrm e^q$. If you think that you can't use them, that's some form of constraint. Without knowing what else you can't use, there's no point in investing time.

Comment: @ValerySaharov: OK -- it's too late here now; I'll try to write it out in more detail tomorrow.

Comment: @ValerySaharov: I just reread your reformulation of the question at the bottom of the post and noticed another shift in the goal posts: Originally you'd written "where $p,q\in\mathbb Q$" (which I'd taken to mean "given $p,q\in\mathbb Q$", as usual); now you write "such that this inequality holds for *any* rational $p$ and $q$". This is impossible, since given $n$, $\sum_{l=1}^nx^l/l!$ is a continuous function of $x$, so for sequences $p_i$ and $q_i$ with the same limit the sum on the left-hand side of the inequality must eventually be less than $1/k$, and then two terms are subtracted from it.

Comment: @ValerySaharov: *No*, it is *not* obvious. That's precisely the problem. You formulate carelessly and assume that what is obvious to you will be obvious to others. It's not. When you write "such that this inequality holds for any rational $p$ and $q$", that means that $n$ and $k$ can't depend on $p$ and $q$. Words matter; their order matters. "for any rationals $p$, $q$ there exist naturals $n$, $k$ so that the inequality holds" (your comment) is not the same as "naturals $n$ and $k$ such that this inequality holds for any $p$ and $q$"  (in the post).

Comment: @ValerySaharov: Now you've even edited your post and added "please do not misinterpret", without changing the sentence that I'd specifically pointed out that gives rise to this interpretation. Sorry, I'm out of this. If you want, I can delete my answer so that the question will appear unanswered and perhaps attract other answers.